# List column (number) custom validation - whole/half values

Tags: custom-list, validation

Using SharePoint 2013, I have a list column of type Number, and I'd like to restrict it to either whole / half numbers, i.e. 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5. But values such as 3.4, 2.6 wouldn't be allowed.

A choice column is unsuitable as the range users will input could go into the 100's.

Can I use custom validation on the column for this and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Number column with decimal places as 1.

Use column validation with formula :

```
=MOD(NCalc,0.5)=0
```